# How connect ammeter from ebay

Tags: multimeter, amperage

sorry for stupid question but I do need help with connect of my ammeter from ebay. I bought this [Ammeter 0-50A](https://www.ebay.com/itm/0-36-Direct-Current-Digitals-LED-Digital-Display-Ammeter-Ampermeter-Panel/142521877008?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=441512420138&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) but there is no connection diagram 
So I try:

1. connect Vcc and GND to 9V and display turn on with value 0.0
2. connect white to negative, after load and black to gnd of load supply - but load (device) not work, it look like there is no connection between white and black thick wire. I try measure resistance and there is 5kOhms

If you look on photos there is some cooper wire between two holes on bottom, on other photos there is R050 but I do not have wire or ressistor on ammeter.

Can somebody help me with connection ? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Junk it and buy a unit with documentation.

Comment: These modules are very handy and convenient **if you can figure out yourself how to use it** maybe some reverse-engineering is needed. If you can't then these modules are pretty useless.

Comment: Why would you buy something that you don't know how to use and that doesn't come with directions!?  Or, at least ask *before* buying.  This boggles the mind.

Comment: Broke. Send it back.

Comment: You want to put 50A through **those** wires.

Comment: Ceterum Censeo: We should have a close reason for "asker bought undocumented stuff and doesn't ask seller, but us, for documentation".

Comment: Asker bought undocumented stuff and doesn't ask seller, but us, for documentation.

Comment: @Marcus: Good point.  I just voted to close for that as a custom reason.

Comment: @OlinLathrop you might want to comment on https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/explicit-close-reason-op-bought-undocumented-stuff-asks-us-instead-of-seller

Comment: There is a high probability that this is a shunt rated meter. Without the shunt, it is a millivoltmeter. Ebay sellers often sell shunt or current-transformer rated meters described as it they are self-contained. The seller of this item has more than 20,000 item listed, probably knows nothing about most of them and cares less.

Comment: There is a large number of listings on eBay for what appears to be the same meter. Some have a connection diagram showing a shunt but not indicating which meters require it. I believe I saw one that warned that the 50 and 100 amp meters require a shunt. I could find none that provided specifications for the shunt. If I owned the meter, I would determine experimentally what is required.

Comment: Thanks. I also think I got bad version without shunt so I order R050 and I will try solder it as shunt ( for my application it could bu just about 0.12W heat on shunt ) so it should work

Answer (score 3):

What this device must be doing is measuring voltage on this R050 (0.05 Ohm) resistor and converting it to the value of current. The device really misses the documentation, and as Leon said in comment to your question you either get documentation for it, or better junk it.

Red/Black wire pair *seem to be* the power supply for the board, power voltage is unknown, thus you can not be sure about its reliable operation unless you disassemble it, draw the circuit, and figure it out yourself, or read it in trusted documentation.

Thick Black/White pair seem to be the one to connect into the circuit to measure the current.

I wonder how much current the device can withstand as R050 resistor must be too weak and will just burn under high currents. Specification is scarce on it, and I guess `Measuring Range: DC0-1A, DC0-5A, DC0-10A, DC0-50A, DC0-100A` means different type of resistor/shunt soldered. Which one did you buy?

Finally, to be sure you understand basics - this device **measures current**, not voltage. It means that you can not just connect it to the poles of the power supply as it will cause enormous current and burnout of the shunt resistor. You **must** connect this current meter device in series with the load.

> it look like there is no connection between white and black thick wire. I try measure resistance and there is 5kOhms

Sounds like shunt resistor is dead.

**My advice: request documentation from the seller,** including connection diagrams.

Comment: I try get documentation but without  success :( I bought 0-50A version

Comment: Sorry I maybe explaint it wrong. my connestion is like normal multimeter  positive -> load - > ammeter -> negative

Comment: Good, so we and you know that it is not you fried the device as you seem have connected it properly :)

Answer (score -3):

You can solder a 50 mOHM = 0.05ohm resistor like on the picture. The tube is the same as a resistor. However be careful and find a through-hole resistor for high Amperes.

The tube is a resistor of a kind.

Or go after a 50 mOHM = 0.05ohm SMD like in the example.

So you undertand that's a SHUNT resistor to measure the current.
[image]

I edited my mistake.

An example of a shunt resistor to buy and a small guide for Shunt resistor.

[MOUSER SHUNT RESISTOR](https://www.mouser.es/productdetail/irc-tt-electronics/lr2512-lf-r050-f?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlleCFQhR%2FzWv3A%2FxA%2Fyx6NUT73Nh4H88=)

[Guide](http://www.resistorguide.com/shunt-resistor/)

Comment: "R050" is 50 **milli**ohms, not 50 ohms

Comment: 50 Ohm resistor to measure 50 Amps?

Comment: YOu are Wright. It's a 50MOHM shunt resistor.

Comment: So write: 50 mOhms (0.05 ohms) not 50 MOHMS (50000000 Ohms)